# How can I extract a specific data from a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tensorflow-lite

I printed a variable `print(detection_result)` which I called from `detection_result = detector.detect(input_tensor)` and it printed

```
DetectionResult(detections=[Detection(bounding_box=BoundingBox(origin_x=209, origin_y=0, width=137, height=135), categories=[Category(index=71, score=0.39453125, display_name='', category_name='tv')])])
```

I just want to extract the values `origin_x=209, origin_y=0, width=137, height=135` how can I implement this? Thanks.

I have tried printing the detector.detect and it wasn't the one I was trying to look for.

Edit: Here is my entire code.

```
import argparse
import sys
import time
import cv2
from tflite_support.task import core
from tflite_support.task import processor
from tflite_support.task import vision
import utils
import tflite_runtime.interpreter as tflite

def run(model: str, camera_id: int, width: int, height: int, num_threads: int,
        enable_edgetpu: bool) -> None:

  # Variables to calculate FPS
  counter, fps = 0, 0
  start_time = time.time()

  # Start capturing video input from the camera
  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_id)
  cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
  cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)

  # Visualization parameters
  row_size = 20  # pixels
  left_margin = 24  # pixels
  text_color = (0, 0, 255)  # red
  font_size = 1
  font_thickness = 1
  fps_avg_frame_count = 10

  # Initialize the object detection model
  base_options = core.BaseOptions(
      file_name=model, use_coral=enable_edgetpu, num_threads=num_threads)
  detection_options = processor.DetectionOptions(
      max_results=3, score_threshold=0.3)
  options = vision.ObjectDetectorOptions(
      base_options=base_options, detection_options=detection_options)
  detector = vision.ObjectDetector.create_from_options(options)

  # Continuously capture images from the camera and run inference
  while cap.isOpened():
    success, image = cap.read()
    if not success:
      sys.exit(
          'ERROR: Unable to read from webcam. Please verify your webcam settings.'
      )

    counter += 1
    image = cv2.flip(image, 1)

    # Convert the image from BGR to RGB as required by the TFLite model.
    rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    # Create a TensorImage object from the RGB image.
    input_tensor = vision.TensorImage.create_from_array(rgb_image)

    # Run object detection estimation using the model.
    detection_result = detector.detect(input_tensor)

    # Draw keypoints and edges on input image
    image = utils.visualize(image, detection_result)
    print(detection_result)
    

    # Calculate the FPS
    if counter % fps_avg_frame_count == 0:
      end_time = time.time()
      fps = fps_avg_frame_count / (end_time - start_time)
      start_time = time.time()

    # Show the FPS
    fps_text = 'FPS = {:.1f}'.format(fps)
    text_location = (left_margin, row_size)
    cv2.putText(image, fps_text, text_location, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
                font_size, text_color, font_thickness)

    # Stop the program if the ESC key is pressed.
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
      break
    cv2.imshow('object_detector', image)

  cap.release()
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()


def main():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
      formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
  parser.add_argument(
      '--model',
      help='Path of the object detection model.',
      required=False,
      default='modeltpu.tflite')
  parser.add_argument(
      '--cameraId', help='Id of camera.', required=False, type=int, default=0)
  parser.add_argument(
      '--frameWidth',
      help='Width of frame to capture from camera.',
      required=False,
      type=int,
      default=320)
  parser.add_argument(
      '--frameHeight',
      help='Height of frame to capture from camera.',
      required=False,
      type=int,
      default=240)
  parser.add_argument(
      '--numThreads',
      help='Number of CPU threads to run the model.',
      required=False,
      type=int,
      default=4)
  parser.add_argument(
      '--enableEdgeTPU',
      help='Whether to run the model on EdgeTPU.',
      action='store_true',
      required=False,
      default=True)
  args = parser.parse_args()

  run(args.model, int(args.cameraId), args.frameWidth, args.frameHeight,
      int(args.numThreads), bool(args.enableEdgeTPU))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a [mre] of your code, including all imports and variable definitions.

Comment: Those may be attributes of the object and if so, you could use an f-string for print `print(f"{dection_result.origin_x} ... and etc ...")`. It may be a collection so you'd want to choose one ... `d = dectection_result[0]`. One trick is to run this in a python shell and experiment.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your response! 

I have tried `print(f"{detection_result.detections}")` and the result I got is 

`[Detection(bounding_box=BoundingBox(origin_x=81, origin_y=102, width=185, height=136), categories=[Category(index=0, score=0.54296875, display_name='', category_name='person')])]`

How can I get inside the array and extract the value? I tried `print(f"{detection_result.detections}")` but I got an IndexError `IndexError: list index out of range` Thanks!